# List not automatically starting and also runs a deleted version of the workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

Under SharePoint 2013 we have run in to an issue where we have a workflow that is set to start automatically by on a new list item being created, but it does not start. This isn't a case where the list item is created by the system account but did notice something odd.

When looking at the workflow in SPD, the options are **Allow this to workflow to be manually started** and **Start workflow automatically when an item is created**

[image]

However, going to the associated list shows **Manual start** as the only option for this workflow

[image]

Additionally the workflow that is being executed when manually started is an old version of this workflow rather than the current one. I've repeatedly published the workflow as well as made minor tweaks to it and republished it to see if it will somehow fix this.

I've deleted all other workflows on this site as well and deleted all past versions associated to the list in the workflow settings on the list properties.

Is my only option to recreate this workflow from scratch, or is there an explanation on why this may be happening?

If it's related, the workflow *Platform Type* is **SharePoint 2010 Workflow**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of messing with this, I thought of a new idea to look into and figured this out moments after posting my question.

The issue was that SPD was publishing an older version from its cache workflow. Following this page [Sharepoint Workflow running on Old Version after publishing](http://luckytechshare.blogspot.com/2015/05/workflow-running-on-old-version.html)

- Close Sharepoint Designer
- Go to **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache** and delete the files and folders inside this location
- Go to **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache** and delete the files and folders inside this location

After doing this and republishing the workflow from SharePoint Designer, it is working as expected.

[image]